# Change label text inside an input field

Tags: javascript, html, input, label

I want to change the payment label ("UepaPay") to credit/debit card. The vendor doesn't allow me to change the payment method name, so I thought maybe I could change it with JS but... the problem here is that I working on Wordpress so I can't change much of the code that I got. I could change the label if have an ID or class but this is not the case.

Look at the screenshot:

[Label problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iys96.png)

Is a way to change the label text without having an id?

Comment: There are many ways to select an element, so we can almost certainly suggest a way to do so, unfortunately images of code are inaccessible, un-searchable and cannot easily be converted into a practicable example. With this in mind, please post your (“*[mcve]*”} code *as* code, in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'querySelelector' method to search for attributes.

```js
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector(['[for=payment-pay]']).innerHTML = 'Credit/Debit Card'
})
```

```html
<label for='payment-pay'>Payment Pay</label>
<button id='change'>Change to Credit/Debit Card</button>
```

Comment: Din't work but helped me a lot i need to try something else i think is because the element is on a mainframe